# How to remove angular CLI generated SSL certificate

Tags: angular, ssl-certificate

in my project, I wanted to get a local SSL connection because of some third-party APIs so I used this `--ssl true` command in the start script .when I start my server first time after that command added to `package.json` i saw this in my CLI  `Generating SSL Certificate`. I want to remove this generated .crt and .key file but I can't find a location of this generated files.I am a windows user.

Comment: Why do you want to remove those certificates? Please see https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a

Comment: because I created new SSL certificate with Trusted Root Certification Authorities.i need to add that into my project otherwise chrome send a warning saying that is not trusted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify your ssl cert by adding the location right after the command line arguments

- `--ssl-cert`
- `--ssl-key`

Like so:

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert \"./ssl/localhost.crt\" --ssl-key \"./ssl/localhost.key\"
```

Also you can put the path to your key and certificate in your angular.json file as follows:

```
{
   "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "projects": {
       "<PROJECT-NAME>": {
           "architect": {
               "serve: {
                   "options": {
                       "sslKey": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.key",
                       "sslCert": "<relative path from angular.json>/server.crt",
                       ...
                   }, ...
               }, ...
           }, ...
       }, ...
   }, ...
}
```

And then you can run:

```
ng serve --ssl
```

If you want SSL on by default then you should add a *"ssl": true,* option immediately below the *sslKey* and *sslCert*.

You can find the angular.json schema at the [Angular CLI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace).

[Link to Angular CLI defaults](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/6449a753641340d8fc19a752e1a1ced75f974efa/docs/documentation/1-x/angular-cli.md)

The default self-signed certs are generated here, defined in the documentation link above:

- sslKey (string): The ssl key used by the server. Default is ssl/server.key.
- sslCert (string): The ssl certificate used by the server. Default is ssl/server.crt.

Comment: cant we remove the old one.I tried this but its points to my old certificate.

Comment: You don't need to remove the old one as you refer to the new one it will take the new one instead.